# Watir-Webdriver & Internet Explorer 11 Issue

Tags: watir

I am facing one weird issue..I am trying to run following watir-webdriver code on internet Explorer 11 and getting strange error. I am running IE in protected mode and IEDriverServer is also placed at correct path. Also, i have created an entry in regedit to work Watir-webdriver on IE 11 ... There is no issue when running the following code on FF.

**Code:**

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie
browser.goto 'http://bit.ly/watir-example'
sleep 5
browser.text_field(:name => 'entry.1000000').set 'Watir'
browser.text_field(:name => 'entry.1000001').set "I come here from Australia. \n The weather is great here."
browser.radio(:value => 'Watir').set
```

**Error**

> ```
>     C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/we
> bdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in `assert_ok': The xpath expression './/input[(no
> t(@type) or (translate(@type,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
> vwxyz')!="file" and translate(@type,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmn
> opqrstuvwxyz')!="radio" and translate(@type,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdef
> ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')!="checkbox" and translate(@type,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX
> YZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')!="submit" and translate(@type,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
> PQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')!="reset" and translate(@type,'ABCDEFG
> HIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')!="image" and translate(@type,
> 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')!="button"
> ```
>
> and transla
>       te(@type,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')!="hidden"
>   an
>       d translate(@type,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')!="d
>       atetime" and translate(@type,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
>       vwxyz')!="date" and translate(@type,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmn
>       opqrstuvwxyz')!="month" and translate(@type,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdef
>       ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')!="week" and translate(@type,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
>       'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')!="time" and translate(@type,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU
>       VWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')!="datetime-local" and translate(@type,'ABCD
>       EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')!="range" and translate(@ty
>       pe,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')!="color"))
>   and **@na
>       me='entry.1000000'] | .//textarea[@name='entry.1000000']' cannot be evaluated or
>        does notresult in a WebElement (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorErro**

Comment: Are you sure that script works in Firefox? It does not work for me. When I look at the page, there is no element with name "entry.0.single" - ie the exception makes sense.

Comment: I have updated code that works on firefox but failed on internet explorer with above error message. (i did wrong copy in my first post. apologize)

Comment: Can you double-check that the error message is correct for that script? The error message says it is looking for the text field with name "entry.0.single".

Comment: Yes, i updated the latest execution outcome in my question.

Comment: Any comments ?  Issue still not resolved...

Comment: Sorry, I was never able to reproduce the exception you got.